# If variable is link, echo link

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I having issues getting a function to echo, where `$lightbox_link1` = `get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')`. I'm fairly new to PHP.

Below is the defining function:

```
// Check for a lightbox link, if it exists, use that as the value. 
// If it doesn't, use the featured image URL from above.
if(get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')) {                            
    $lightbox_link1 = get_custom_field('lightbox_link1');
} else {                            
    $lightbox_link1 = $image_full[0];
}
```

Echo Function:

```
<?php if ($lightbox_link1 = get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')) {
     echo '<a href="<?php echo $lightbox_link1; ?>" data-rel="prettyPhoto[<?php echo $post_slug; ?>]"></a>';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if ($lightbox_link1 = get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')) {
```

should be

```
<?php if ($lightbox_link1 == get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')) {
```

`=` is used for assignment

`==` is used for comparison

`===` is used for typesafe comparison

also you can't declare `<?php ...  ?>` inside another `<?php ... ?>`

to get something like `<?php ... <?php ... ?> ... ?>`

take a look at what you did up to here:

```
 <?php if ($lightbox_link1 = get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')) {
    echo '<a href="<?php
```

Instead, using doublequotes in your `echo` statement will allow for the php variables inside to be parsed, so you could just do

```
echo "<a href='{$lightbox_link1}' data-rel='prettyPhoto[{$post_slug}]'></a>";
```

to get

```
<?php if ($lightbox_link1 == get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')) {
     echo "<a href='{$lightbox_link1}' data-rel='prettyPhoto[{$post_slug}]'></a>";
} ?>
```

Comment: You wrote the same thing for both lines. `<?php if ($lightbox_link1 = get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')) {` should be `<?php if ($lightbox_link1 == get_custom_field('lightbox_link1')) {`

Comment: sorry I was re-editing for clarity and made a copy paste mistake